# Use PHP function in a smarty file

Tags: php, function, smarty

I have created the following function in php.  I want to call it from a smarty file, but I keep getting an error from the smarty. What am i doing wrong?

```
<?php
function getCommission($inputid)
{
    $database="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    mysql_connect (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx);
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hb_aff WHERE id = $inputid") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 return $info['total_commissions'];
 } 
}
 ?>
```

Part of the tpl code is:

```
     {include file="getCommission"} 
<tr>
    <td >{$lang.convrate}</td>
    <td >{$affiliate.conversion} %</td>
    <td >{$lang.commissions}</td>
    <td ><input size="3" value="{getCommission($affiliate.id}" name="total_commissions"/></td>
                            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed a parenthesis here before the last accolade :

```
"{getCommission($affiliate.id}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to [register the function](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.register.plugin.tpl) with Smarty, rather than using `{include}`:

```
<?php
$smarty->registerPlugin("function","getCommission", "getCommission");
```

Comment: sorry for the edit i tried to comment.

Now, i read somewhere that i need to include my function in the smart.class.php file. Do i have to do that too except from that?

Also can u please describe me how to call the function?

Will the {getcommission} be enough cause my function has 1 parameter.

Comment: I don't know your code structure, but you call `registerPlugin` after you initialize your smarty object. Then yes, the function is available through `{getCommission}` just like the usual smarty functions.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help, i am going through the smarty documentation again tryin to figure this out.